# Getting this text "404-File or Directory not found " in image while using htmlToImageConverter.ConvertUrlToImage() mehtod of hiqpdf.dll

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using hiqpdf.dll to convert my html page into bmp image. I am able to generate image but my image is not showing the html page content. Image is showing  "404- File or Directory is not found.The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I am using following code.

```
Public Function ConvertHTMLtoImage(objScreenshot As Screenshot) As String
    Dim imgPath As String = imgOutputPath
    Try
        ' create the HTML to Image converter
        Dim htmlToImageConverter As New HtmlToImage()
        ' set a demo serial number
        htmlToImageConverter.SerialNumber = objScreenshot.serialNumber.ToString()
        ' set browser width
        htmlToImageConverter.BrowserWidth = objScreenshot.browserWidth
        ' set HTML Load timeout
        htmlToImageConverter.HtmlLoadedTimeout = objScreenshot.imgLoadTimeOut
        ' set whether the resulted image is transparent (has effect only when the output format is PNG)

        ' set triggering mode; for WaitTime mode set the wait time before convert
        Select Case objScreenshot.triggeringMode
            Case "Auto"
                htmlToImageConverter.TriggerMode = ConversionTriggerMode.Auto
                Exit Select
            Case "WaitTime"
                htmlToImageConverter.TriggerMode = ConversionTriggerMode.WaitTime
                htmlToImageConverter.WaitBeforeConvert = Integer.Parse(objScreenshot.imgLoadTimeOut)
                Exit Select
            Case "Manual"
                htmlToImageConverter.TriggerMode = ConversionTriggerMode.Manual
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                htmlToImageConverter.TriggerMode = ConversionTriggerMode.Auto
                Exit Select
        End Select
        ' convert to image
        Dim imageObject As System.Drawing.Image = Nothing
        Dim imageFormatName As String = objScreenshot.imgFrmt.ToLower()
        Dim imageFileName As String = [String].Format("{0}{1}.{2}", imgPath, objScreenshot.imgOutputName, imageFormatName)
        ' convert URL
        imageObject = htmlToImageConverter.ConvertUrlToImage(objScreenshot.htmlURL)(0)
        imageObject.Save(imageFileName.ToString())

    Catch ex As Exception
        objScreenshot.ErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString()
        ErrorLog.RecordError(HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.ToString, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString, ex)
    End Try
    Return imgPath
End Function
```

I am not able to find route cause behind this.can someone tell me what is route cause behind this issue. How will i get my html content in image.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `objScreenshot.htmlURL` inside the function ConvertHTMLtoImage. It may be invalid or missing. The 404 error you get occurs when the browser (`htmlToImageConverter.ConvertUrlToImage` in this instance) tries to access the URL. You can also try to open `objScreenshot.htmlURL` in an ordinary browser to see if it is accessible.